# Column name corresponding to largest value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

for below dataframe data:

```
x  y  a b c 
2  6 12 1 2
1  2  4 6 8
```

I want result in new column(i.e d) that returns name of column with max value only among a,b,c.

```
cols
a
c
```

I'm trying to find maximum values from three columns and return column name.But instead of selecting all the rows of dataset,I want to select rows of only these three columns.I'm using the following code:

```
def returncolname(row, colnames):
    return colnames[np.argmax(row.values)]
data['colmax'] = data.apply(lambda x: returncolname(x, data.columns), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest solution I can think of is `DataFrame.dot`:

```
df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0).dot(df.columns)
```

**Details**
First, compute the maximum per row:

```
df.max(1)
0    12
1     8
dtype: int64
```

Next, find the positions these values come from:

```
df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0)     
       x      y      a      b      c
0  False  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False   True
```

I use `eq` to make sure the comparison is broadcasted correctly across columns.

Next, compute the dot product with the column list:

```
df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0).dot(df.columns)
0    a
1    c
dtype: object
```

---

If the max is not unique, use

```
df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```

To get a comma separated list of columns. For example,

Change a couple values:

```
df.at[0, 'c'] = 12
df.at[1, 'y'] = 8
```

Everything is the same, but notice I append a comma to every column:

```
df.columns + ','
Index(['x,', 'y,', 'a,', 'b,', 'c,'], dtype='object')

df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0).dot(df.columns + ',')
0    a,c,
1    y,c,
dtype: object
```

From this, strip any trailing commas:

```
df.eq(df.max(1), axis=0).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',') 
0    a,c
1    y,c
dtype: object
```

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: @VroJ Edited, also please see my footnote.

Comment: @VroJ can there be multiple max values?

Comment: this is exactly I wanted to know.There are multiple max value around 14.

Comment: I did this by taking data in another dataframe with code in the question but since there was 5,50,000 observation it became difficult to merge the data.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind returning the first occurence of the maximum (or if maximum will always be unique), use `idxmax`

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']].idxmax(1)
```

```
0    a
1    c
dtype: object
```

If you need all occurences of a maximum, use [coldspeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663031/3483203)